# A question about UITabBarItem

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, xcode

```
- (id) init

{
    [super initWithNibName : nil
                    bundle : nil];  
    UITabBarItem *tbi = [self tabBarItem];  
    [tbi setTitle : @"Hypnosis"];   
    UIImage *i = [UIImage imageNamed : @"Hypno.png"];   
    [tbi setImage : i];         
    return self;        
}
```

Consider the above sample code, my questions are :

1

There is a "setImage" method call, but I cannot find the corresponding "Image" property 
in documentation.

2

UIImage *i is being assigned by the statement "[tbi setImage : i]"  to the Image property.
Does "*i" being retained by tbi?  If so, should we release "i" immediately after the assignment ?

Hope that some knowledgeable person would help me to find the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there doesn't need to be an `image` property declared for a class to have a `setImage:` method--a property can be implied to exist by the existence of setters/getters. `i` will be retained by the TabBarItem--that's the responsibility of the setter API. This is standard behavior. Finally, do not release `i` after calling `setImage:`. You do not have an owning reference to `i` since it was returned from a factory method, not an [ [ alloc ] init ] invocation. HTH

Comment: @nielsbot, thanks for your very precise and clear answer.  But the fact that a property can be implicitly defined by (setters/getters) is still a bit unsettling for me.

Comment: i see what you're saying. i sort of made up the terminology here. before objective-c had declared properties and property accessor syntax, all you had was getter/setter methods. Having a getter/setter pair could sort of be taken as defining an imaginary property internal to the class.

Comment: or consider c++, java, etc.. .where you have setter/getter methods for private member vars

Comment: finally: adding properties using obj-c 2.0 property declaration syntax actually creates setter/getter methods for you. they're there, just not declared.. so perhaps that's unsettling from another angle.

Comment: @nielsbot, thanks for the additional info. Learning about the "implied property creation" syntax was quite a surprise for me. But on second thought there may be some advantage to that. That is memory can be saved since the property comes into existence only at run time when its value is set. So the running system can carry less unused properties at a given time.

Comment: Also, please correct me if I am wrong. This property creation on the fly during run time ability is special to "object driven by message" languages such as Objective-c. Have used c++ and c# before and have not notice any similar property creation options. The memory savings and the added flexibility provided by this should be considered as an advantage quite unique to Objective-c.

Comment: Well, what I'm saying is having `-(void)setImage:(UIImage*)image` and `(UIImage*)image` is just like having `UIImage * Class::getImage()` and `Class::setImage(UIImage * image)` in C++. Having those pairs of methods declared implies the class has an image property, but you don't know anything about the implementation. There is, however, no runtime creation of properties involved.

Comment: IMO Obj-C does have a lot of advantages of C++ due to it's dynamic dispatch and metaprogramming (ability to modify classes at runtime for example). I think it's more related to how people actually think.

Comment: @nielsbot, I agree with you that which language is better depends on how people think. And wish to add that it depends on what is the job on hand. There may be a typo on your last comment, in your first sentence.  Do you really mean ... advantages of c++ or advantages over c++ ?

Comment: yeah.. 'over', not 'of'. Thanks.

Comment: Also thanks for the c++ code segment, I was wrong thinking that c++ does not have a corresponding syntax for adding a property away from the class definition.  So c++ is not limited by its syntax to add things to its classes at run time.  As you say, we do not know the implementation. It may be possible for them to change the compiler implementation so that c++ can have some form of metaprogramming also.  @nielsbot, thanks again for your help, I have really learnt a lot from you …

Answer (score 0):

1) First of all, if there is `setX:` method it doesn't necessary mean that there is `x` property (I think you understand that). But as I checked documentation there is neither `image` property, nor `setImage:` so it is private api. As it is said in ViewController PG you shouldn't ask for existing UITabBarItem, but create it yourself and assign to yourVC tabBarItem property. Something like this:

```
...

UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed : @"Hypno.png"];
UITabBarItem* theItem = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Hypnosis" image:image tag:0];
self.tabBarItem = theItem;
[theItem release];

...
```

2) You should not release an image in this situation, cause you don't own it. It is autoreleased by `imageNamed:` method. But if you have created it by `[[UIImage alloc] init..]` method it would be your responsibility to decrease its retain count. And "yes" image will be retained by tabBarItem.

Hope this'll help!